# Where can I find the Visual Studio Express executable?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I had visual studio 2013 express edition installed on my windows 8.1 PC. I then installed VS 2013 professional. Now I want to run express edition to verify certain features available between express vs pro but I cannot find how can I launch express version. Whenever I search for it via Windows 8.1 search box, I just get pro version.

Can anyone point me to location where express version executable is installed so that I can launch it? VS is installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0` and I assume that its somewhere here where I should have both express and professional versions installed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can just search for 'express' in the Win8.1 search and it'll show up.

Otherwise go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE` and open `VSWinExpress.exe`. Professional can be opened with `devenv.exe`.

For Visual Studio 2017 the path is slightly changed. You can find it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`. Change 'Professional' to 'Community' for the community edition.

Comment: Helpful post for **Visual Studio 2015 Community** also. It is also available at the same location under `deven.exe`.

Comment: Works for **Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise** aswell. Same location under `deven.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is named WDExpress.exe. I needed to look it up to add a shortcut to run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For 2015 Visual Studio Express it is located at 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe

Comment: you may want to edit this answer to cover for people who don't have the same absolute file path as you :)